# Nature of exempt allowance under section 10

Tags: income-tax, india

I'm filing income tax return for assessment year 2019-20. I'm facing problem in putting the details for section 10. The `Nature of Exempt Allowance` column is showing 14 different choices as shown in the below snapshot:

[image]

The expenses which I'm filing under this section are as below:

- Office uniform
- Technical books and magazines
- Driver's salary
- Broadband connection bill
- Car fuel bills
- Sodexho meal vouchers

Can someone help me selecting the correct sub-section in the drop down?

**Update**: This amount is being shown as `Total amount of any other exemption under section 10` in my form 16. The sub-sections are listed as `Books And Periodicals Exemption`, `Car Exemption`, `Children Education Exemption`, `Driver Exemption`, `MEAL VOUCHER EXEMPTION` etc.

Answer (score 0):

This would depend on how it is shown in the form 16.

The items you have listed are taxable unless the company pays these as expenses. Sodexo upto 18,000 can be given by a company. It is not included in the form 16, under income from salary

Comment: I've updated my question regarding form 16. It is being reflected in my form 16 as exemption. Can you please suggest now? which section should I choose in ITR-1 (Sahaj)